# Is the statement "for any real number x, abs(x − 1) = abs(x) − 1" true or false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the book, Discrete Mathematics with Applications, it says that this statement is true, however if we set x = 0,

> abs(0 - 1) = abs(0) - 1
>   abs(-1) = 0 - 1
>   1 = -1

which makes me think that its false. I know books can be wrong, but I just want to make sure I didn't do something stupid.

Comment: do you mean $|x-1|=|x|-1$? this is nor true for any real $x$, set for example $x=0$

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard: it is true for $x\geq1$.

Comment: The book might assume x is a positive integer.

Comment: @Clayton - In the book the only requirement is that x is a real number, x≥1 is not specified.

Comment: that has to be written here

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - I did, it's in the question.

Comment: @maou: then the statement is false...it is only true for $x\geq1$ and false for $x<1$. In other words, it is not true for all real $x$. As Did states, though, the book may assume elsewhere that the "universe" of numbers is positive integers.

Comment: It might be useful to specify the page of the book on which this statement occurs. There might be additional clues there to indicate why the book made this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is only true for $x\geq1$, and it is false for all $x<1$.

Answer (score 4):

If it is **Ex.15**, page 197 of : Susanna S.Epp, [Discrete Mathematics with Applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=PPc_2qUhXrAC&pg=PA197) (2010), it is **not** the absolute value function, but the *floor* function :

> For all real numbers $x, \lfloor x − 1 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor − 1$.